# Javascript- how to get an array of property values inside nested objects

Tags: javascript

I have an object that looks like the following. I want to get an array of a specific property on the inner maps.

```
outerMap : {

    innerMap1: {
    a: 1
    b: 2
    c: 3
    },

    innerMap2: {
    a: 4
    b: 5
    c: 6
    }
}
```

For example if i want an array of the 'a' properties inside innerMaps. 
Output would be `[1, 4]`
How can I achieve this in javascript?

Comment: What code you tried so far?

Comment: A lot has to do with how general purpose you need a solution to be.  For example, `[outerMap.innerMap1.a, outerMap.innerMap2.a]` is a valid answer.  That's why seeing your attempt will help others give help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
const obj = {
    innerMap1: {
        a: 1,
        b: 2,
        c: 3
    },
    innerMap2: {
        a: 4,
        b: 5,
        c: 6
    }
}

let results = []

for (let innerMap in obj) {
    results.push(obj[innerMap].a)
}

console.log(results)
```

You can do this by simply looping through the `obj`'s keys, and the selecting the `a` key from each.

Comment: This works perfectly. I tried it before but I had syntax wrong. Forgot the let in the for loop. Thanks!

Comment: what about dynamic property? @marcus

Comment: Instead of .results.push(obj[innerMap].a you could do results.push(obj[innerMap][dynamicVar] @Supercool.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
let object={
  outerMap:{

  innerMap1: {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3
  },

  innerMap2: {
  a: 4,
  b: 5,
  c: 6
  }
 }
}

function getArray(property){
return Object.keys(object.outerMap).map( (innerMap) =>{
    return object.outerMap[innerMap][property]     
})
}
console.log(getArray('b'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```